# How to stop default value of a disabled input field to be sent in request

Tags: html, reactjs

I have one input type number which i have disabled on one specific condition and for the same I have setup default value too. When the field is disabled then also, that default value is getting sent in the request. I don't want to send default value if the field is disabled. How can i achieve the same.

Default value is set in a separate function as:

```
document.getElementById('maxNumGoodPathTests').value="1";
```

This is the code for input field:

```
<label>
    <input type="number" min="1" max="1000" id="maxNumGoodPathTests" 
    disabled={this.state.goodChecked} onBlur={this.handleValue}/> &nbsp;
    good path tests
</label>
```

Comment: You should probably have no use of document.getElementById in React. You should probably be using state, and in your handleValue method, check gather the data to submit based on your conditions. It sounds like you might be relying on the browser form submit. Don't do that but use an onsubmit handler.

Comment: how you are sending data in request?

Comment: You can make use of `ref` - https://reactjs.org/docs/uncontrolled-components.html

Answer (score 0):

If you are using react this is the correct way of reading input:

```js
class App extends React.Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state={
            input_value : '',
            goodChecked : false
        }
        this.handleInputChange = this.handleInputChange.bind(this);
    }
    handleInputChange(el){
        this.setState({
            //considering that your text is in el.target.value
            input_value : el.target.value
        })
    }
    render(){
        return(
            <input
                 //your settings
                 value={this.state.value}
                 onChange={this.handleInputChange}
            />
        )
    }
}
```

Now, if your input is disabled and will stay that way you can remove the handleChange method and use the default value for input_value in state. Now you can use your input_value based on your goodChecked in your onSubmit method:

```js
onSubmit(){
    const sendingParam = this.state.goodChecked?'fixed_value':this.state.input_value
}
```

hope this helps.